# If the current line has the search string, do not print it and its previous line

Tags: awk

How to do this?
If the current line has the string "9999-01-31", do not print it and its previous line.
Otherwise print.

e.g.
in.txt:

```
Test1 end1
Date1 : 2023-01-12 Date2 : 2023-07-23
Start Xhy
Date1 : 2022-02-12 Date2 : 9999-01-31
Abc dfg
Date1 : 2021-03-09 Date2 : 2021-06-24
Hello world
Date1 : 2019-05-23 Date2 : 9999-01-31
```

Expected output:

```
Test1 end1
Date1 : 2023-01-12 Date2 : 2023-07-23
Abc dfg
Date1 : 2021-03-09 Date2 : 2021-06-24
```

I tried:
awk -f in.awk in.txt

```
last = $0
!/9999-01-31/ {next; next}
{print last $0}
```

Comment: With GNU sed: `sed -z 's/[^\n]*\n[^\n]*9999-01-31[^\n]*\n//g' in.txt`

Comment: Hey, my implementation in `sed` =)

Comment: A not entirely serious contribution: `tac in.txt | awk '/9999-01-31/{getline; next}1' | tac`

Comment: Ed will kick your ass if you use `getline()` just to get the nextline =) More seriously: [avoid the use of `getline()`](http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline) when it's not absolutely required

Comment: @albertkao9: you have plenty of choice ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `awk` idea:

```
$ cat in.awk
/9999-01-31/ { last = ""; next              }
last         { print last; last = ""        }    # if last is non-blank then print and clear it
             { last = $0                    }
END          { if (last != "" ) print last  }    # flush last line?
```

To verify this works when `9999-01-31` does not exist in the last line in the file:

```
$ cat in.txt
Test1 end1
Date1 : 2023-01-12 Date2 : 2023-07-23
Start Xhy
Date1 : 2022-02-12 Date2 : 9999-01-31
Abc dfg
Date1 : 2021-03-09 Date2 : 2021-06-24
Hello world
Date1 : 2019-05-23 Date2 : 9999-01-31
Good-bye world                            <<< added to file

$ awk -f in.awk in.txt
Test1 end1
Date1 : 2023-01-12 Date2 : 2023-07-23
Abc dfg
Date1 : 2021-03-09 Date2 : 2021-06-24
Good-bye world
```

Comment: This works when 9999-01-31 does not exist in the last line in the file. Thanks!

Comment: `if (last) print last` would fail if the last line was just `0`, `if (last != "") print last` would be better, assuming the OP doesn't have an empty line at the end of the file or, if they do, they're OK with it being removed.

Answer (score 3):

`awk 'NR%2==1{line=$0; next} !/9999-01-31/{print line; print}' in.txt`

This command should do the job.
It checks if the current line number is odd (NR%2==1), and if so, it stores the current line in the variable line and moves to the next line.
If the current line does not contain the string “9999-01-31” (!/9999-01-31/), it prints the stored line and the current line.

Comment: assumes last line in file contains `9999-01-31`; add the line `Good-bye world` on the end of `in.txt` and this `awk` script will fail to print that last line

Comment: @ markp-fuso, you are right. You described additional test cases. Thanks!

Comment: @markp-fuso it actually assumes that last line is a date.
i.e. 
```text
date
text
date```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `awk`, you should have `Perl` too:

##### `Perl` >= 5.36:

```
perl -gpe 's/\n[^\n]+\n[^\n]+\b9999-01-31\b//g' file
```

##### `Perl` < 5.36:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\n[^\n]+\n[^\n]+\b9999-01-31\b//g' file
```

##### `GNU sed`

Like Cyrus wrote in comments, the (close to) same regex can be used with `GNU sed`:

```
sed -z 's/[^\n]*\n[^\n]*9999-01-31[^\n]*\n//g' file
```

```
Test1 end1
Date1 : 2023-01-12 Date2 : 2023-07-23
Abc dfg
Date1 : 2021-03-09 Date2 : 2021-06-24
```

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `\n` | '\n' (newline) |
| `[^\n]+` | any character except: '\n' (newline) (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `\n` | '\n' (newline) |
| `[^\n]+` | any character except: '\n' (newline) (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `\b` | the boundary anchor between a word char (\w) and something that is not a word char anchor |
| `9999-01-31` | '9999-01-31' |
| `\b` | the boundary anchor between a word char (\w) and something that is not a word char anchor |

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Ruby:

```
ruby -e '$<.read.split(/\R+/).
    each_slice(2){|x,y| puts [x,y] unless y[/9999-01-31$/]}' file
```

Or a second Ruby:

```
ruby -e '$<.read.scan(/(^.*)\R+(^.*)/){|o,t| 
           puts [o,t] unless t[/9999-01-31$/]}' file
```

Or similarly in Perl:

```
perl -0777 -nE 'while (/(^.*)\R+(^.*)/gm){ 
    say "$1\n$2" unless $2=~/9999-01-31$/ ; }' file
```

Or use `paste` to turn the file into two by two lines with awk:

```
paste -sd'|\n' file | awk -F'|' '!($2~/9999-01-31$/) {printf "%s\n%s\n", $1,$2}'
```

If you have a HUGE file and want to deal with it two lines at a time, you can use `getline` in awk:

```
awk '
{
    getline line
    if(line~/9999-01-31$/) next
    printf "%s\n%s\n", $0, line
}' file
```

Any of those prints:

```
Test1 end1
Date1 : 2023-01-12 Date2 : 2023-07-23
Abc dfg
Date1 : 2021-03-09 Date2 : 2021-06-24
```

Answer (score 0):

### awk procedure:

```
awk '/9999-01-31/ {next} {print last; last=$0}' file
```

### output

```
Test1 end1
Date1 : 2023-01-12 Date2 : 2023-07-23
Start Xhy
Abc dfg
Date1 : 2021-03-09 Date2 : 2021-06-24
```

The procedure is similar to the OP's failed version. The print block is only reached if the current line did not contain the match and the last line is updated for the next print encounter. As last is not assigned a value until the first record has reached the print block, a superfluous blank line may be inserted at the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk plus tac:

```
$ tac in.txt | awk '/999-01-31/{c=2} !(c&&c--)' | tac
Test1 end1
Date1 : 2023-01-12 Date2 : 2023-07-23
Abc dfg
Date1 : 2021-03-09 Date2 : 2021-06-24
```

or just using awk:

```
$ awk '{rec=rec $0 ORS} !(NR%2){if (!/999-01-31/) printf "%s", rec; rec=""}' in.txt
Test1 end1
Date1 : 2023-01-12 Date2 : 2023-07-23
Abc dfg
Date1 : 2021-03-09 Date2 : 2021-06-24
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you can have more than 1 previous line that you want to omit, and the lines that have a date all start with Date and a digit:

```
awk '
  !/^Date[0-9]/ {last=last sep $0;sep=ORS;next}
  !/9999-01-31/{print last ORS $0}
  {sep=last=""}
  END{if(last) {print last}}
' in.txt
```

If `in.txt` contains:

```
Test1 end1
Date1 : 2023-01-12 Date2 : 2023-07-23
Start Xhy1
Start Xhy2
Date1 : 2022-02-12 Date2 : 9999-01-31
Abc dfg1
Abc dfg2
Date1 : 2021-03-09 Date2 : 2021-06-24
Hello world
Date1 : 2019-05-23 Date2 : 9999-01-31
Date1 : 2019-05-23 Date2 : 9999-01-31
test
```

Output

```
Test1 end1
Date1 : 2023-01-12 Date2 : 2023-07-23
Abc dfg1
Abc dfg2
Date1 : 2021-03-09 Date2 : 2021-06-24
test
```